# ListView's last item appears to be deleted on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, notifydatasetchanged

In my android application, I have and Array Adapter(for populating listview) and a Fragment having ListView. The data in listview is retrieved using Shared Preferences. The problem is that when any item of the listview is chosen to be deleted, last item seems to be deleted every time.

Like, if the list has 5 items in total and you choose to delete the 2nd item after press and hold. After delete, the 5th item seems to be deleted in list unless you press back button and then come back to the same fragment then you see the correct items present in the listview.
ListView doesn't get refreshed properly after closing the dialog box immediately, you have to come back to the fragment.

Please help, I have been trying to fix it since months without success. Many Thanks!

**Adpater Class:**

```
     public class DuasListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        // class variables
            private  Context context;// to save context
            private List<String> duas;// to save list of stores
            LayoutInflater inflater;// so save layout inflater for the view



        public DuasListAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> duasList) {

        super(ctx, R.layout.adapter_list_duas, duasList);
            context = ctx;// save context
            duas = duasList;// save list of stores
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);// save inflater layout


        }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder=null;
            // if view is not loaded
            if (!(convertView instanceof View)) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list_duas, parent, false);
                // load the view from holder class
                holder.background = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_duas_list);
                holder.iv_duatype = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_duatype);
                holder.tv_dua_arabic = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dua_arabic);
                holder.tv_dua_no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dua_no);
                //holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                // set the tag for future use
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            // if view is loaded
            else{
                // get view from tag
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {



                    final View view = v;
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:{
                                        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                                        int index = holder.duaIndex;

                                        ((MainActivity) context).removeItemFromList(index);
                                    //  ((MainActivity) context).loadDuasListFragment();

                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                        // No button clicked
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setMessage("Delete Dua from Favorites?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

                        return false;
                    }

                });


            return convertView;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {

             int duaIndex;
            LinearLayout background;// background to display color for read and unread messages
            ImageView iv_duatype;
            TextView tv_dua_arabic;// title of message
            //TextView tv_dua_ref;// message by and message created on
            TextView tv_dua_no;
    }
}
```

**Fragment Class:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = inflater.getContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_duas, container, false);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ll_back_duas_list_header = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ll_back_duas_list_header);
    ll_back_duas_list_header_title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ll_back_duas_list_header_title);
    lvDuaas = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_duas);



    String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
    String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
    duas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < versesList.length; i++) {
        if (versesList[i].length() > 0)
            duas.add(versesList[i]);
    }

    duasAdapter = new DuasListAdapter(context, duas);
    lvDuaas.setAdapter(duasAdapter);
}

/** method removing the accurate item form list, checked by debugging**/

public void removeItemFromList(int index) {
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
        String identifier = versesList[index];
        new FavoriteDuas().removeDua(identifier);
        updatedData();
    }



    public void updatedData() {
        boolean keyIsFavSel = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyIsFavSelected, false);
        if (keyIsFavSel)
            new SharedPreferencesSupplication().save(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyFavVerses, "a1"));
        String verses = new SharedPreferencesSupplication().read(SingletonClass.keyListOfVerses, "a1");
        String[] versesList = verses.split(",");
         duas = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < versesList.length; i++) {
            if (versesList[i].length() > 0)
                duas.add(versesList[i]);
        }
         duasAdapter.clear();

if (duas.size() > 0) {

            for (String object : duas) {

                duasAdapter.insert(object, duasAdapter.getCount());

            }
        }

            duasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand what exactly is happening. What is the problem with that last item and the pressed item? Please rephrase your problem.

Comment: `which involves the use of SharedPreferences.` but how? I see that you do. Do i have to find out what? Better you tell. `you have to come back to the fragment.`? Sorry but you did not tell that you 'left' a fragment. You not even named a fragment before. So please explain better.

Comment: @greenapps Please check. Hope I am clear this time!

Comment: Show where you are setting `DuasListAdapter` as your `ListView`'s adapter.

Comment: You say that the listview is retrieved using shared preferences. Ok let it be that way. But what are you doing with shared preferences after deleting and item from the list? You did not tell that you would do someting with shared preferences. Please explain better. It is unclear for me where after closing the dialog box 'you are' as apparently you are somewhere from where you can go back to a fragment.

Comment: Please check again..thaks alot.!! have added more code as well!